# Android apk download using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, appium

I was trying to download the android apk file located at Hockey App share point but could only download a part of file not the complete file. Below is the code attached.

Below is the code that I have used to alter firefox configuration to handle the download pop-up

```
     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
           // profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "Downloads");
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");// MIME type for apk file
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Also, I tried using Content Type header("text/html; charset=utf-8") value  shown in the Network monitor of Firefox. But that didn't work as well.

Any other approach other than Selenium is also appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply do a wget for your file?

Comment: I tried using wget and curl but the problem is download link is appended with dynamic values at the end which signifies new app version and avtoken string. And I m unable to retrieve the that value to pass on to the wget/curl command.

Comment: Have tried this:   wget -O abc.apk -r -A apk https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/e87f26c75b8f418dfsfjhj85a5a67c8e5cc49b/app_versions/157?format=apk&avtoken=08a243a8515f6

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the api provided by hockey app. Its pretty easy .. you can get the build url from available versions and then download. I have written a script pretty straightforward.

https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api

P.S. You should use the token from a developer account . Tester account doesnt get the build_url. But that shouldnt be difficult just ask for a read only token.

Comment: How can we retrieve app specific app version and app details using those APIs? I have multiple app and different version of those app listed in the hockey app